# git doesn't read environment variables when merging with --no-ff

Tags: git, githooks, husky

I have a `commit-msg` where I use `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` for whitelisting specific developers for certain commit message standards.
In normal scenarios, `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` is always defined and shows the correct author of the commit.
When I am doing a release with these steps below

```
git checkout -b release/1.2.0 develop
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff release/1.2.0
```

git opens an internal message prompt for the merges.

```
Merge branch 'release/1.2.0'
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

After I save it and exit, inside my `commit-msg` hook the `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` are both empty. And not only those values, but also the email, date, and any other author-related variable.

What's the problem here?

Comment: How do you set `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`? Do you use `sudo`?

Comment: It's set by git.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables - Check it.

Comment: From the linked text: "*Some of Git’s general behavior as a computer program depends on environment variables.*" That is Git doesn't set these variables, it expects you set them and then Git uses their values.